# How to persist C# objects with WebServices?

Tags: c#, web-services

I wrote this WebService in C#:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    TestClass testObject = new TestClass();

    public string GetData()
    {
        testObject.Counter++;
        return string.Format("Test Value: {0}", testObject.Counter);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }
}
```

It's a WebService and each time I invoke my WebService it recreates everthing. So my counter never increase and each time I invoke `GetData()` the WebService return "1".

What are the solutions to persist my data between each WebService invoke.

1. Database, I would like to avoid this solution,
2. State on the client, How ?
3. session, Is there an easy way to use this?
4. persistent service.  Is this working?

Do you know articles than explain how to persist data with WebService?

Thank you,

Comment: If your webservice is only running on 1 server you can use session state or Cache.  If your web services is running on more than one server then you will have to use a database to store the value.

Comment: What is the intended lifespan of the data you wish to persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a stateful web service, by using `Session` for example. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service).

However, something [to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009863/how-good-and-or-necessary-are-stateful-web-services) in most cases, for scalability reasons. Your service calls should always be independent of each other.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting link. I have the same question as TraderJoeChicago: if you need state, what should you use. 1) Database, 2) State on the client, 3) session, 4) persistent service. Is there an easy way to use 3 ? Is 4 working ? In my case i would like to avoid the database for performance reasons.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You could track the counter in the HttpContext.Cache and increment the values there:

```
int counter = (int) HttpContext.Current.Cache["ServiceCallCounter"];
counter ++;
HttpContext.Current.Cache["ServiceCallCounter"] = counter;
```

Note that you have to activate it first and note that this cache does not persist a Application-Pool recycle:

```
<system.serviceModel>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```