# session management with spring ws backed webapplication

Tags: java, spring, web-services, web-applications, architecture

I am trying to create a webapplication, which will use a js front end and invoke Spring WS in the backend. Let's say this is a shopping site kind of website. So, I could have services like `OrderService` `InventoryService` `ShippingService` and so on. The only thing that needs session is the shopping cart of the user. Now, just for this shopping cart, does it make sense to use a servlet container for session management? Or, should I have `CartService` that persists session information to the database?

What is the best practice when it comes to session management with WebServices? I guess, the best practice really is to keep the service stateless, but how can I authorize users if I have stateless webservices?

Is it a good practice at all to use a servlet container just to do session management and then have different controllers acting as proxies to the webservices?

I am attaching a picture to make you understand the context better.
[image]

Comment: Well I guess you can use a kind of client access key in HTTP request header; I mean: from browser (after login attempt) a client access-code is passed in a custom http header; on server side in servlet container you can get this client access token and check if it's valid token; then you cna use it in order to invoke web services

Comment: So should a single servlet/filter act as an authorizer for all web services?

Comment: Yes I0d definitively use a single servlet or filter

Comment: if I am going to use a servlet/filter, then it would have access to the session, wouldn't it? And if it has access to session and can check if user is qualified to access the webservice, then I wouldn't need any sort of security at my WS? Is this (using a servlet as security gate) the best practice to secure your webservices from ajax requests?

Comment: Nope... you wouldn't; you must acces to the request and get the http header cotaining the client access key. Something like request.getHeader("CUST-KEY"); and then check if this key is valid or less (according to some well defined rules). This means that browser MUST pass this http header in every call

Comment: @AngeloImmediata do you have any links to any tutorial that implements such an access key concept?

Comment: I guess that the best approach you may use is the OAuth 2.0; here few links you may see: 1) http://oauth.net/2/ 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth 3) https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified 4) https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: @AngeloImmediata here's the situation, I have say, http://myapp.com/testapp1 and http://myapp.com/testapp2. Two different applications that would have different set of users. And some users from app1 can access my web service and some users from app2 cannot. In both cases, what you are suggesting is that I should not have no protection at WS, but have app1 and app2 authorize users and make internal calls (from app1 and app2's server side) to WS?

Comment: Nope; i'm saying that you can use this approach to generate a client code; then pass this code to the WS too and there check if the code is valid or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If webservice is stateless, how do I know that an ajax request is authorized? How do I know that ajax request is coming from user1 of webapp1, who is authorized? and not from user2 of webapp2, who is not authorized to access the service?

Good question. Quick answer would be :

1. For *Basic Authentication* : username:password is base64 encoded and stored in the *Authorization* http header for each request that the client sends. See [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). The header looks like this:

   `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

   With [spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/), configuration can be like this:

```xml
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('REMOTE')" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
```

2. For *form* based authentication of WS, take a look on [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/).

   - First you sent a post request to */j_spring_security_check*. This request will return the Cookie which will then be used by any subsequent request against the Web Service. Here they store it in a text file:

     `curl -i -X POST -d j_username=user -d j_password=userPass -c /tmp/cookies.txt
     http://localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check`
   - Then you can use the cookie from the file to do further authenticated requests:

     `curl -i --header "Accept:application/json" -X GET -b /tmp/cookies.txt
     http://localhost:8080/app/api/foos`

   The xml spring security configuration can look like this:

```xml
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('REMOTE')" />
        <form-login />
    </http>
```

Answer (score 5):

> How can I authorize users if I have stateless webservices?

1. If you app uses external ws, then rather common approach is described [here](http://www.slideshare.net/alvarosanchezmariscal/stateless-authentication-for-microservices).
2. If all the ws are part of your delivery, you can surely use [spring-security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).
3. A very common approach is also to have an (apache) http server as a proxy with something like ldap for both, authentication and authorization.

> Is it a good practice at all to use a servlet container just to do session management and then have different controllers acting as proxies to the webservices?

I would think it is not. As also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009863/how-good-and-or-necessary-are-stateful-web-services) you can only benefit from keeping your Web Services stateless and if you need to maintain state between requests, use cookies.

If the state (cart) should survive the logout, something like *CartService* sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: on your point 3 - do you mean I should use basic authentication? if its http server, how will I store session specific information?

Comment: We currently use basic authentication (so it works) but I would not call it a _best practice_. Anyway, apache can do a form authentication and manage sessions : check [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html).

Comment: Ok, I guess it will require usernames to be on file for it to authenticate.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but leaving the servlet container handle sessions while the web services are stateless IS a good practice.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding.  
- stateless ws is indeed a good practice  
- having an additional servlet container with controllers as  proxies to the real web services sounds not a good practice to me.

Comment: @MilosGregor ok. if webservice is stateless, how do I know that an ajax request is authorized? Let's say my service is supposed to be accessed from two different apps and only certain kind of users from these two different apps are authorized to access. How do I know that ajax request is coming from user1 of webapp1, who is authorized? and not from user2 of webapp2, who is not authorized to access the service?

Comment: @Jay: please, see my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to the [Spring-WS security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#security)

Check [here](https://github.com/gregturn/learning-spring-ws/tree/security/learning-spring-ws-server), for a sample that uses WS-Security in a Spring Boot app. Specifically, see WebServiceServerConfig.

Comment: ok this link was helpful. But from this code here - https://github.com/gregturn/learning-spring-ws/blob/security/learning-spring-ws-server/src/main/java/com/greglturnquist/learningspringws/WebServiceServerConfig.java I couldn't tell why a dispatcherServlet needs to be mentioned as part of configuration. Does this mean that a dispatcher servlet will manage all query requests and we need to specify the path for this webservice in that callback?

Comment: Sorry i am not an expert of SpringWS, if you want give me your mail, i will send you a very good Project Exemple developed by my self for a Job Test, with Spring-Boot and Swing Interface